# How to shut down the system while using GNOME desktop environment in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, and I have GNOME and KDE desktop environments installed on it. While I am using Unity, I am able to see the shutdown option and able to shutdown the system by clicking that option. But I am unable to find such an option if I am logging in selecting GNOME. In GNOME I have options to log-out and suspend. But this is not what I want. Is there a way similar to that what we have in unity?

Comment: 11.10 has reached end of life and will no longer be supported.  You need to upgrade.

Comment: if you want to shutdown your system, `sudo poweroff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold down Alt and the Suspend menu item will become Shut Down. You can also just tap the power button on your computer, and a shutdown dialog will appear.

Just so you know, Ubuntu 11.10 is no longer supported and 12.04 has a much-improved version of GNOME Shell - complete with a Shutdown item in the session menu. Upgrading could solve any confusion with this in the future.